# C++, Access violation

Tags: c++

I have started to learn C++ some weeks ago and now I have a problem with my current project.

I wanted to write templates, that allow me to save objects into binary datas and load them again later. Here ist the code of these templates:

```
#ifndef TOOLS_H
#define TOOLS_H

#include <fstream>
#include <string>

namespace Tools
{
    template <class T>
    void writeBinaryFile(std::string filename, T object)
    {
        std::ofstream of(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        of.write((char*) &object, sizeof(T));
        of.close();
    }

    template <class P>
    P readBinaryFile(std::string filename)
    {
        P temp;
        std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        ifs.read((char*) &temp, sizeof(P));
        ifs.close();
        return temp;
    }
}

#endif
```

I created a class called GameSettings. The header data is:

```
#ifndef GAMESETTINGS_H
#define GAMESETTINGS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"

class GameSettings
{
public:
    GameSettings();
    GameSettings(std::string playerName, bool sound, int volume, int level);
    ~GameSettings();

    void setPlayerName(std::string playername){ playerName = playername; };
    void setSound(bool sound){ this->sound = sound; };
    void setVolume(int volume){ this->volume = volume; };
    void setLevel(int level){ this->level = level; };

    const std::string getPlayerName() { return playerName; }
    const bool getSound() { return sound; }
    const int getVolume() { return volume; }
    const int getLevel() { return level; }

private:
    std::string playerName;
    bool sound;
    int volume;
    int level;
};

#endif
```

With the cpp-data:

```
#include "GameSettings.h"

GameSettings::GameSettings(std::string playerName, bool sound, int volume, int level)
{
    this->playerName = playerName;
    this->sound = sound;
    this->volume = volume;
    this->level = level;
}

GameSettings::GameSettings():
playerName(""),
sound(true),
volume(0),
level(0)
{
}

GameSettings::~GameSettings()
{
}
```

When I start the main-function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GameSettings.h"
#include "Tools.h"

    int main()
    {
        GameSettings* gs = new GameSettings("Andrew", true, 100, 3);
        Tools::writeBinaryFile<GameSettings>("gamesettings.bin", *gs);

        gs->setPlayerName("TEST");

        *gs = Tools::readBinaryFile<GameSettings>("gamesettings.bin");

        std::cout << gs->getPlayerName();
        std::getchar();

        return 0;
    }
```

an error occurs:

Unhandled exception at 0x5a1cad54 (msvcp100d.dll) in Mohrhuhn.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfeeefeee.

Can somebody help me?

Sincerly, Andrew

Comment: First thing - there is much better circular dependency protection called "#pragma once", look it up.
Also what did you try to find the error? Did you run it through a debugger and see whats on the stack? I don't think that anyone here will do it for you.

Comment: Do you know roughly there it occurs? Your first step should be to attempt to debug so you can isolate where the error manifests itself.

Comment: I have debugged it with Visual c++ 2010 Express. A file called xutility opens and the error occurs in this area:

Comment: for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
   *_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
   (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = 0;
  _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = 0;
  }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the root of the trouble is

```
*gs = Tools::readBinaryFile<GameSettings>("gamesettings.bin");
```

You read raw bytes to a variable that contains std::string. It may ruin char pointer inside it. So, any call to playerName should fail or result in UB.

Only POD types can be read/write this way. A bit more I found on another web-page: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/39764/

Comment: Seems to be so. If I clear the line everything works. What can I do to fix this Problem?

Comment: Maybe streams could help? Add ">>" and "<<" operators to your class and use c++ io streams.  Or maybe something like Boost.Serialization.

Comment: You could serialize each member instead, so your function header will look like `void writeBinaryFile(std::string filename, const GameSettings& object)`.

Comment: UB: undefined behaviour, they like to talk in UB, POD, etc :P

Answer (score 3):

The template you implement to serialize the object will not work because casting the `std::string` to `char*` and saving `sizeof(std::string)` will not save the content of the string.

Check the saved file, but I guess you need to implement properly serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

First of all writing down binary files by just dumping them from memory is a bad idea since you might incur in lots of additional problems (e.g. shallow copies, polimorphism, etc..)

```
    return temp;
```

You are returning a temporary object that is being destroyed after the function exits.

Change your code into

```
gs = Tools::readBinaryFile<GameSettings>("gamesettings.bin");

...

template <class P>
P* readBinaryFile(std::string filename)
{
    P* temp = new P();
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    ifs.read((char*) temp, sizeof(P));
    ifs.close();
    return temp;
}
```

and everything will work out properly (psst. remember to free the memory!)

Comment: @user3159049: use references instead (though not as return type)

Comment: The temporary object is a red herring, and not necessarily even accurate.  the NRVO optimization can avoid copying and destroying it, but even if there is a temporary object, it will be copied. The problem is entirely in making a binary image of a type that isn't trivially serializable, which your answer didn't fix at all.  The last sentence is totally wrong, as it won't work out.

Comment: I thought so but allocating the object on the heap fixes the issue

Comment: @David: Memory layout changes may cause undefined behavior to do different things, but there still is undefined behavior here, which will start failing again at the drop of a hat.  Actually, I'm pretty positive it will still fail, despite your claim it "fixes the issue".  It simply won't fail during function return, but on the *next* access to the `std::string` member, even farther from the actual problem.